# EFCore Add Unique Index using Shadow Property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a Unique Constraint across a property "Blah" and a Shadow FK

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ParameterOption>().HasIndex("Blah", "ShadowForeignKey").IsUnique();
```

But when I try and migrate, it doesn't recognise "ShadowForeignKey".

I have tried using ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ParameterOption>().Property<string>("ShadowForeignKey")
```

which I thought might let the model be able to use the shadow FK

But that ends up needing a migration where it tries to create ...

ShadowForeignKey1

Because ShadowForeignKey already exists as a shadow property.

Please help!

Comment: `HasIndex("Blah", "ShadowForeignKey")` should work. Could you clarify what di yo mean by *"it doesn't recognise "ShadowForeignKey""*? Or better provide small model reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was an ordering issue in `OnModelCreating` the Shadow Property Foreign Key was introduced lower in the file.

To reference a Shadow Property it (maybe unsuprisingly) needs to be higher in the file.